# Syntax error in ruby script (unexpected keyword_end and unexpected $end)

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

I am writing some code as a solution for a programming problem. I have just introduced a new function into my solution which is causing the following errors. Note that the errors are not there without this function.

```
search.rb:48: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
search.rb:68: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

I realize that this is caused by a mispaced end. I just can't find it. (I have marked the location of the first error with a comment. The second error is the last line of code and not shown here.)

```
def processing_function
    qcount = pcount = $n
    qstrength = 0
    $query_hash.each do |qkey, qvalue|
        print "Q",qkey,": "
        $page_hash.each do |pkey, pvalue|
            qvalue.each_index do |i|
                pvalue.each_index do |j|
                    if qvalue[i]==pvalue[j]
                        qstrength = qstrength + qcount*pcount
                    end
                    pcount--
                end #** This is line 48. First error occurs here. **#
                qcount--
                pcount=$n
            end
            if qstrength!=0
                print "P",pkey," "
            end
            qstrength=0
        end
        print "\n"
    end
end
```

Comment: You should learn ruby syntax. For example, you can't use `val--` code.

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev I just started learning yesterday and I  am coming from C & C++. Thank you for pointing it out. I updated the code.

Comment: That's ok. So updated code still has an errors?

Comment: No that resolved the error. Thank you. You should add that as the answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: Please don't edit your question in a way that fundamentally changes the original question, e.g. by removing a syntax error which was the original source of your issue.

Comment: Take the time to read the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby). While it's not an official style guide, it has a lot of good tips. In your code, put spaces around your operators and use two spaces to indent. Also, you're using `$globals`, which cause code smell. Odds are really good you don't need them if you write your code correctly. `$query_hash`, `$page_hash` and `$n` should probably be parameters instead of globals.

Comment: @theTinMan Thank you for that suggestion. I am reading it right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby doesn't have `--` or `++` operator. Use, for example `+= 1` instead.

[There is short article about differences for C/C++ and Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/to-ruby-from-c-and-c-/).